# vuejs add class to <td> with a method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following `<td>` structure in my Vue.js app:

```html
<td class="editable" :class="{green: is_by_user(item['h_bid_source'])}" v-on:dblclick="set_custom(item, 'income_h_bid')">{{ item.income_h_bid }}</td>
```

and users are able to update the value in the table using the following method:

```js
set_custom (item, key) {
    if (moment(this.date_start).isSame(this.date_end)) {
        let new_value = prompt("Enter updated value:");
        this.$http.post("/api/revenue", {
            "date":     moment(this.date_start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            "site_id":  item.site_id.toString(),
            "key":      key + "_u",
            "val":      new_value}).then(res => {
                // Update view with new value
                for (let row of this.report) {
                    if (row.site_id == item.site_id) {
                        row[key] = new_value;
                        // TODO: add class
                    }
                }
            }, res => {
                // TODO: Handle server error
            });
    } else {
        alert("Custom values not available when date range is selected.");
    }
}
```

I want to add the class `green` to every `<td>` after `set_custom()` is called. What is the correct idiomatic Vue.js method to do this?

Comment: *Every* `td` or *that* `td`?

Comment: that specific `td`